# working with events. Raising from local var

Tags: c#, .net, events

There is code sample in the chapter about events in the book about c#:

```
class CountDown
{
    private uint _seconds;
    public CountDown(uint seconds)
    {
        _seconds = seconds;
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            uint n = _seconds;
            while (n > 0u)
            {
                var tick = Tick;              ///??????
                if (tick != null)
                    tick(n);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                n--;
            }
            var finished = Finished;          ///??????
            if (finished != null)
                finished();
        }).Start();
    }
}
    public event Action<uint> Tick;
    public event Action Finished;
```

What is the reason for creating local copy of event (tick and finished) and raising event via it? Is it common practice and have some sense? I tried but couldn't get it from the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the reason for creating local copy of event (tick and finished) and raising event via it?

It avoids the possibility of `Tick` becoming null *after* the nullity check but *before* the call. If you had:

```
if (Tick != null)
{
    Tick(n);
}
```

... and the final listener was unsubscribed when you'd already got into "if" body, you'd get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: The event is acting like a value type in that new variables are copied.  But its an immitable ref type that behaves like we are dealing with two copies of a ref type.  Isnt this unsafe behavior for an immutable object?

Comment: Doesn't tick=Tick mean that tick refers to the same set of methods which are hooked to Tick, and if I null Tick tick became null too?

Comment: @Dork - no changing `Tick` does not change `tick`.  Once `tick` is assigned to a reference setting `Tick` to a difference reference (even null) does not change `tick`.  It is exactly the same as `string s1 = "1234"; string s2 = s1; s1 = null;` - at the end `s2` is still "1234" and not null.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: What do you mean by "behaves like we are dealing with two copies of a ref type"? Delegates are immutable just as strings are...

Comment: As we add and remove subscribers to the event that changes the value of the event.  Changing values after construction isnt allowed with immutable objects.  What am I missing?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: It changes the value of the *variable*, to refer to a different instance. It doesn't change which handlers the *existing delegate instance* refers to. Again, it's just like strings - if you write `foo += "bar";` that doesn't append `"bar"` into the existing string; it changes the value of `foo` to refer to a different object.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, between you nullchecking the event and it being called, something might've unsubscribed, making the event `null`, which would throw a (probably unhandled) `NullReferenceException`, which would be annoying to users, to say the least.